# Record locked when updating value via Apex when triggered from Process Builder

Tags: apex, approval-process, process-builder, field-update

So I have an Apex method running off the process builder but when I try to update a record via the invoked method it says the record is locked.  Perhaps the reason it won’t update is because the process hasn’t completed yet?  How can I update a record via Apex triggered from the process builder?

```
@invocablemethod
public static void updateBenefit(list<ea_app__c> app){
                app[0].Benefit_Amount__c = calcBenefit(app[0].name);
    // ----> this is the issue here  <----
    update app;
}

public static decimal calcBenefit(string appID){
    decimal benefit = 0.0;
    integer coeff = getCoefficient('2015');
    decimal max = getMax(getfamilySize(appID));
    benefit = (1-(getIncome(appID)/max))*(getFuelCost(appID)/coeff);
    return benefit;        
}
```

Comment: figured it out.  I needed to do most of this via a trigger before update.  If I'm (you're) going to be editing the object that triggers the process you must use a trigger and cannot use the process builder.  That is because you need to use BEFORE UPDATE or BEFORE INSERT.  Process builder is AFTER UPDATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out. I needed to do most of this via a trigger before update. If I'm (you're) going to be editing the object that triggers the process you must use a trigger and cannot use the process builder. That is because you need to use BEFORE UPDATE or BEFORE INSERT. Process builder is AFTER UPDATE –